# Isomorphisms on intersections of coverings induce isomorphism in homology.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $X_1, \dots, X_k$ be an open covering of $X$ and $Y_1, \dots, Y_k$ an open covering of $Y$. If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map s.t. for all $i$ we have: $f(X_i) \subseteq Y_i$ and the restrictions:
$$
\bigcap_{i \in A} X_i \rightarrow \bigcap_{i \in A} Y_i
$$
induce isomorphisms in homology, for all finite sets $A \subseteq \{1, \dots, k\}$. Then I need to show that $f$ induces an isomorphism in homology.

I must admit that I‘m a bit lost on how to proceed here. I thought about using Meyer-Vietoris Sequences which, I believe, would give me something like:
[image: Sequence]

Where the maps between the homology groups of the intersections are isomorphisms. But I dont know if this is the correct way to proceed, since I have no idea how to show that the map $H_n(X)\rightarrow H_n(Y)$ is an isomorphism. I‘d be happy if someone could give me some hints:)

Comment: Damn, who hurt you @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $k=2$, your idea is correct, there is a homomorphism between the long exact sequence
$$\cdots\to H_n(X_1)\oplus H_n(X_2)\to H_n(X)\to H_{n-1}(X_1\cap X_2)\to\cdots$$
and
$$\cdots\to H_n(Y_1)\oplus H_n(Y_2)\to H_n(Y)\to H_{n-1}(Y_1\cap Y_2)\to\cdots,$$
and the homomorphism are isomorphisms $H_n(X_1)\oplus H_n(X_2)\simeq H_n(Y_1)\oplus H_n(Y_2)$ and $H_{n-1}(X_1\cap X_2)\simeq H_{n-1}(Y_1\cap Y_2)$. Now $H_n(X)\to H_n(Y)$ is also an isomorphism by the [five lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma). For general $k$ the proof is similar but involves inducting on $k$.